# Read an existing xml file and apply changes

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to learn how to read a XML file and do changes using C#.

Problem:
The XMLfile already exists. I would like to read the file and search for a specific element which has another element with an attribute:

```
<ELement>
    <Element2 Attribute = "Value" /> 
</Element>
```

The problem is if this element "Element2"  does not exist in the xml file I would like to create it under the same path.

Here is my actual code.

```
private void UpdateConfig(string configPath, string serverName)
{                
    string oldServername = null;
    XElement config = XElement.Load(configPath); 
    CreateConfigBackup(configPath);                 

    try
    {
        //which could be Null if the element does not exist in xml file.
         oldServername = config.Element("WebGUI").Element("ServerIP").Attribute("Value").Value.ToString();

         oldServername = oldServername.Split(':').FirstOrDefault();                 
        // Config updaten
        config.Element("WebGUI").Element("ServerIP").Attribute("Value").SetValue(serverName);
        }
        else
        {
            XElement ELM = new XElement("ServerIP");
            ELM.SetAttributeValue("Value",serverName);
            config.Element("WebGUI").Add(ELM);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {                
        if (oldServername == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(configPath+ "enthält nicht das Element Server in der Web-Konfigurationsdatei.");                    
        }
    }
    SaveConfig(config, configPath);
}
```

Comment: The code of your example will not compile due to you have an else statement without an if before.. Anyway, of course for doing what you want you should check if the element exists and if don't then create it.

Comment: I changed the wording of your question a bit to what I -think- you meant to say.  My apologies if my change is not accurate!

Comment: You should mention what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: @squillman came here to see the exciting xml file, a rare thing indeed :)

Comment: @Crowcoder what is actualy wrong is that the Variable "oldServername" is null because the asked value is null. that means that the element does not exist in the .xml file. The Question is 
-how do i search for the element ?
-if element does not exist. how can i add a ELement with Attribute under a Element in a existing .xml file

Comment: If you hardcode `oldservername = null` instead of allowing the exception to throw, does it work? I think you just need standard null checking.